# missing : after property ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here... line 3 is reporting missing : after property ID

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#imagegallery img').each(function({$(this).css({ width: '100%'});});

    $('#imagegallery').cycle({
        timeout: 0,
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        width: '100%',
        height: 'auto',
        next: '.next',
        prev: '.prev' 
    });



    $("#imagegallery").touchwipe({
        wipeLeft: function() {
            $("#imagegallery").cycle("next");
        },
        wipeRight: function() {
            $("#imagegallery").cycle("prev");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Problem is with this line:

```
$('#imagegallery img').each(function({$(this).css({ width: '100%'});});
```

should be:

```
    // missing ) --------------------v
$('#imagegallery img').each(function(){$(this).css({ width: '100%'});});
```

Although you can shorten it like this:

```
$('#imagegallery img').css({ width: '100%'});
```

Comment: I'd say it should be: `$('#imagegallery img').css({ width: '100%'});` ;)

Comment: @Nick - Agreed. Just finished updating. :o)

Answer (score 2):

I also have an error show to definition of my function like below.

```
function test(a) {
   //do something;
}
```

My case to solve the problem by change it to:

```
test : function(a) {
   //do something;
}
```

The error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close paren in

```
// $('#imagegallery img').each(function({$(this).css({ width: '100%'});}); 
// should be:
$('#imagegallery img').each(function(){$(this).css({ width: '100%'});});
```

Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

This error also shows up when declaring a class method with `function` keyword (could have slipped in with copy-pasting):

```
class T {

    function name() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Should be just:

```
class T {

    name() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The closing parenthesis missing is the each one

```
$('#imagegallery img').each(function({$(this).css({ width: '100%'});});)
```

**Or**

```
$('#imagegallery img').each(function({$(this).css({ width: '100%'});}));
```